# Error in android program

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

> I am using android 4.2.2 i.e. API 17 but error comes call require API level 12(current min is 8): android.hardware.usb.UsbManager#openDevice

```
public List<UsbSerialDriver> probe(final UsbManager manager, final UsbDevice usbDevice) 
    {
        if (!testIfSupported(usbDevice, FtdiSerialDriver.getSupportedDevices())) 
        {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        final UsbDeviceConnection connection = ***manager.openDevice(usbDevice)***;
        if (connection == null) 
        {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        final UsbSerialDriver driver = new FtdiSerialDriver(usbDevice, connection);
        return Collections.singletonList(driver);
    }
```

Comment: If you intent of using this `manager.openDevice()` function, then set the `minSDK` version to 12, see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html#openDevice(android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice)

Comment: thank you naresh and goody i have got it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html#openDevice%28android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice%29):

**public UsbDeviceConnection openDevice (UsbDevice device)**

> **Added in API level 12 Opens the device so it can be used to send and**
>   **receive data using UsbRequest.**
>
> Parameters device the device to open Returns a UsbDeviceConnection, or
>   null if open failed